# Regex get number from string which not have 0 at end (not divide by 10)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need get number from string which not end with zero (nod divide by 10)

I tried

```
RegExp('[0-9]*[1-9][^0]', 'i').test("dasda dasdas 111110 dasdasda")
```

But still get 11111

Update: i need get only result if text will be "dasda dasdas 111114 dasdasda".

aasda 312 asdas - true,

asa 333 dasda - true,

dasd 10 sdas - false,

asda 11 asdas - true,

dasd 1110 sadasda - false

1000 asddasd - false
1001 adas -true

Comment: What's the desired result for that string? Post some more examples along with their expected result!

Comment: add `\b` as word boundaries

Comment: What about `"asda 1230 asda"` and `"asda 123 asda 230 asda 110"` and `"asda112asda"` and `"asda"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
\d+[1-9]\b
```

and if only one numerical digit also is desired, as @Aguardientico pointed:

```
\d*[1-9]\b
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/bw6Fkg/1)

Comment: A minor change suggestion: `\d*[1-9]\b` it will also match

Comment: yep, this will catch also one numerical digit (if it is necessary)

Answer (score 1):

This could work too  `\d*[^\D0](?!\d)`
or just `\d*[1-9](?!\d)`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
\d*[1-9](?!\d)\
```

`d*` matches any number (repetition of digits) - or none (important for single digit numbers!)
`[1-9]` ensures that the last digit is non-zero
`(?!\d)` a negative lookahead to ensure that the next character is anything but a number

This passes your test cases but **also**
1) assumes there can be single digit numbers you want to match for example:
`1` but not `0`
2) assumes you want to match numbers surrounded by non-whitespace characters for example `asdf123ghi`

If (2) is not the case, you can drop the lookahead for a less expensive option (go with Vitaliy's 2nd solution in this case).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways but to test for a match the following should work:

```
/[\b[0-9]+[^0]{1}\b/ig.test(some_string);
```

This will test if there is a number in the string that does not end in 0. The \b are word bounds and constrain the match to with in word bounds, space for all intents and purposes. [0-9]+ is character class for any number of consecutive digits with at least one match. Then [^0]{1} says any not 0 field of length 1. The last piece is the special constraint that makes it work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. However, if you test that string with the above regex you get false.

Comment: Sorry, but it matches `[[[01` or `100$`

Comment: This is because word boundary, \b, detects where word and non-word meet. The word class is defined as [A-Za-z0-9_] and non-word as everything else. I suggest word boundary because it works well generally and none of the op's example contained that character. Depending on the input, using a specific (custom) character class in place of the \b character check will work.